# PHP Counter that does the same thing as CSS Counter?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Currently I have the following code.

```
<li class="track clearfix" data-index="0" data-file="/some-mp3-file.mp3" itemprop="track" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicRecording">
    <span class="track-data">
      <span class="name" itemprop="name">Holding On</span>
    </span>
    <ul class="actions">
         <li><a href="downloadlinkhere.com" target="_blank">Download</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="track clearfix" data-index="0" data-file="/some-mp3-file.mp3" itemprop="track" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicRecording">
    <span class="track-data">
      <span class="name" itemprop="name">Holding On</span>
    </span>
    <ul class="actions">
         <li><a href="downloadlinkhere.com" target="_blank">Download</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Alright the above code returns the following look with my current style sheet using this CSS.

[image]

Sorry for the poorly drawn circles.

```
ol.tracklist li.track span.track-data:before {
    content: counter(tracklist) ".";
    margin: 0px 5px 10px 0px;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: "ProximaNova-Bold",Sans-Serif;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

the issue I'm having currently is that I need to count the numbers of each post here as the `data-index` portion also and I can't seem to figure out how to do this properly.

I'm using WordPress and everything will be included in a loop, pulling content from a meta table structure.

***EDIT:*** 
The below is a quick mock up of basically what I plan on doing, everything seems to be working fine except for the portion I'm having issues with above.

```
<?php
$post_id = (isset($_GET['id'])&&$_GET['id']!=0) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : '';
$post_links = get_post_meta($post_id,'download_links',TRUE);
$link_array = explode(" ", $post_links); 
?>

<?php foreach($link_array as $single_link) { ?>

<li class="track clearfix" data-index="0" data-file="<?php echo $mp3_link; ?>.mp3" itemprop="track" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicRecording">
<span class="track-data">
  <span class="name" itemprop="name"><?php echo $mp3_title; ?></span>
</span>
<ul class="actions">
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $single_link; ?>" target="_blank">Download</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Do you have the PHP code you are/will be using to generate this?

Comment: @Leland I haven't made it yet, as I've been having this issue currently with hard code, I could quickly code it and edit if it's required?

Comment: Yeah go ahead and do that. What you're asking for is pretty easy, but the PHP code will be entirely dependent on your implementation.

Comment: @Leland view edit

Comment: `foreach ($link_array as $index => $single_link)`, `<?php echo $index; ?>`